# Node sass could not find bindings for current environment but binding file is present

Tags: node.js, node-sass

Missing binding `/Users/shiverma/Desktop/project/web/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-51/binding.node`
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: OS X 64-bit with `Node.js 7.x`

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - OS X 64-bit with Node.js 7.x
  - OS X 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (72)

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to build the binding for your current environment.

I've tried cache cleanup, npm rebuild node-sass, npm rebuild node-sass --force but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've upgraded from Node 7 to Node 12. Node-sass is a native module, so it needs to be rebuilt for each new node version. To support Node 12, you'll need to upgrade to node-sass 4.12